# Fire event on Scrolling Vue.js overflow:auto height:100vh

Tags: vue.js

Hi I have problem firing event when I scroll. I want event to fire when I scroll menu and not whole page. If you look at console, and disable overflow and height in CSS for #app, event will fire. Please check link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Marko_TON/rbmp9hke/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign id of inner `div` element. Let's say `longlist` here.

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="longlist" class="some-long-list">
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add scroll event to the `longlist` element. Here you should use `mounted()` instead of `created()`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: null
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll (event) {
      // Any code to be executed when the window is scrolled
      console.log(event)
      console.log("metallica")
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.list = document.getElementById('longlist')
    this.list.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed () {
    this.list.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
})
```

Also, change css to enable scrolling only inside inner div.

```css
#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* padding: 20px; */
  transition: all 0.2s;
  height: 100vh;
  /* overflow: auto; */
}

.some-long-list {
  background:red;
  width: 300px;
  margin:0px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have this in your pen:

```
...
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
...
```

...so your event listener is attached to the whole window. Try selecting the relevant element first with something like `document.getElementsByClassName('my-list')[0]` or similar to attach the event listener to the element itself.

e.g.

```
...
created () {
    const list = document.getElementsByClassName('my-list')[0]
    list.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
...
```